# Which TotalWar games have Multiplayer coop campaigns?

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

Recently I got TotalWar Shogun 2. I am playing multiplayer coop campaign with a friend and love it.
Sometime later I got TotalWar Troy and discovered it has no multiplayer coop campaign...

So my question is

**Which TotalWar games have Multiplayer coop campaigns?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Total War game since *Empire* has had a 2 player coop campaign:

- Empire: Total War
- Napoleon: Total War
- Total War: Shogun 2
- Total War: Rome II
- Total War: Attila
- Total War: Warhammer
- Total War: Warhammer II
- Total War Saga: Thrones of Britannia
- Total War: Three Kingdoms

CA has said multiplayer campaigns will be added to *Total War Saga: Troy* at a later date

Comment: Empire total war cant be played in multiplayer campaing, only battle